# Java regular expression for password validation

Tags: java, regex, validation

I have sample of Java REGEX which I want to use on a dynamic way to validate the password. I don't know is this possible through the regular expression, but I would like to hear some opinions. Other options always there are, but I would like to implement it like this.

Sample REGEX to validate a password:

```
((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})
```

The point is that possible to  to have dynamic number of digits for example? It is configurable and can be changed. Numbers must be mixed up through the entire length of the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a minimum of 2 digits and 3 lowercase letters, for example, you could use the following:

```
((?=(?:.*\\d){2})(?=(?:.*[a-z]){3})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})
```

Comment: We probably should add `^` and `$` or be explicit that this regex should be used with `meatches` method. Also wouldn't it be better to use `\D*\d` instead of `.*\d`? Wouldn't `.*` require backtrack if it consume too much?

Comment: @Pshemo: I didn't add anchors since this is Java, and I'm assuming he's using `.matches()` which has implicit anchors. About `.*` - yes, it's less than optimal but hardly relevant for password validation.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I was confused since you used non-capturing groups so it looked like you ware also trying to focus on performance of this regex :)

Comment: @Pshemo: Yeah, force of habit :)

Comment: WoW! To be honest, I was expecting that someone will write "That is not possible" :). Anyway thanks for fast and nice answer.